# How can I execute a Javascript function when the value of a HTML textbox changes due to document.getElementById("textfield").value = "";

Tags: javascript, html

I want to execute a function whenever the value of a textbox changes. This is normally done with the following:

```
onchange="myfunction()"
```

The above does not work for me because I have some additional requirments.

1. I need the function to execute as soon as ANY text is inputted rather than waiting for the user to hit "Tab" or select another element.
2. I want the function to execute whenever JavaScript is used to automatically update the field (see below statement).

   ```
   document.getElementById("textfield").value = "";
   ```

Comment: Just call `myfunction()` from the code that changes the element. There's nothing that will do it automatically as far as I know. Events are generally only for externally-triggered actions, not actions by the script itself.

Comment: For #1 there is the [*input* event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), but support from older browsers may be lacking. For the second, there have been various attempts at [*mutation events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Appendix_F:_Monitoring_DOM_changes) but none have been successful or widely adopted. Polling is an option, but generally considered a bad idea. Have the code that changes the value [*dispatch a change event*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) on the element.

Answer (score -1):

Try jquery

`$(".textfieldClass").change(function(){
    //do something with the new text: $(this).val()
});`

https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: You should only respond with a library answer if it's tagged or mentioned explicitly in the question.